# Is there an alternative to joining 3 or more tables?

Tags: sql, database, select

Is it a good idea to join three or more tables together as in the following example. I'm trying to focus on performance. Is there any way to re-write this query that would be more efficient and faster performing? I've tried to make is as simplistic as possible.

```
select * from a
join b on a.id = b.id 
join c on a.id = c.id
join d on c.id = d.id
where a.property1 = 50 
    and b.property2 = 4 
    and c.property3 = 9 
    and d.property4 = 'square'
```

Comment: as per my little knowledge it is looking good only ..

Comment: for performance you need to replace `*` with only the columns you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance wise, I think it really depends on the number of records in each table, and making sure that you have the proper indexes defined.  (I'm also assuming that `SELECT *` is a placeholder; you should avoid wildcards)

I'd start off by checking out your execution plan, and start optimizing there.  If you're still getting suboptimal performance, you could try using temp tables to break up the 4 table join into separate smaller joins.

Answer (score 4):

If you want faster performance,  make sure that all of the join's are covered by an index (either clustered or non-clustered).  It looks like this could all be done in your query above by creating an index on the id and appropriate property columns of each table

Comment: voted up for this important point for performance what a beginner person,like me, used to miss .. :)

Comment: I'm not familiar with how to do an index. Can you explain more? Can you give an example?

Comment: A primary key is an example of a Clustered Index. Use Indexes carefully as essentially they are a copy of the data for faster retrieval, but if there is a lot of data in the table, the index will take up a significant amount of disk space. Here is a really good article on the basics of indexes: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-index-basics/

Answer (score 4):

You could make it faster if you only selected a subset of the columns, at the moment you're selecting everything from all 3 tables.

Comment: Right, I can select a subset...but my concern is that is this really a good practice? or best practice?

Comment: Well, it's only good practice if you don't need everything from all 3 tables. Say for example you didn't need 10 columns and there was 1 million rows, that's 20 million columns worth of data that you're not retrieving, hence it'll perform faster :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a normalized database, this is the best you can do, in terms of structuring a query and the joins in place.

There are other options to look at, including adding indexes on the different join and select clause columns, denormalizing the table structures and narrowing the result set.

Adding indexes on the join columns (which appear to be primary keys, so may already be indexed) will help with the join performance, indexing the columns in the select clause will help with speeding up the filtering on each table.

If you denormalize, you get a structure with duplicate data with all the implications of duplicate data (data maintenance issues mostly), but you gain performance as you no longer need to join.

When selecting columns, you should specify which ones you want - using `*` is generally a bad idea. This way you only transfer the data that the application really needs.